# Which of the following is a binary operation?

Tags: functions, binary-operations

This question was asked to me by a student of mine and I am not able to make any progress on this question.

> Let $A=${1,2,3,4,5} , then which of the following is a binary operation?

(a) {((1,1),1),((1,2),1), ((1,3),1),((1,4),1) ,((1,5),1))}.

(b){((2,1),2),((2,2),2), ((2,3),2),((2,4),2) ,((2,5),2))}.

(c){((1,2),2),((1,3),3), ((1,4),4),((1,5),5) ,((1,1),1))}

(d) none of the above.

I tried using the definition of binary operation and function: Let $A$ be an non empty set then a function $f$ from $A \times A$ to $A$ is defined as a binary operation or a binary composition on $A$.

But I am not able to deciede using that I need help.

Comment: [Operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)) "is a function which takes zero or more input values (also called "operands" or "arguments") to a well-defined output value." *Binary* means two arguments.

Comment: All the three above are "binary" and a functions (there are no repeted pairs) but they are not total, i.e. they are not defined for all pairs in $A \times A$.